Accessing report parameter in chart Customizer code
I'm implementing the answer here accessing parameter in customizer
I defined parameter like
<categoryDataset>
                <dataset>
                    <datasetRun subDataset="chartDataset">
                        <datasetParameter name="SOME_CHART_PARAM">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SOME_PARAM}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>

While running, I got error like
 1. Unknown parameter SOME_CHART_PARAM in dataset chartDataset.

So I tried adding a parameter as below.
    <subDataset name="chartDataset" uuid="f9034d6f-c83f-446d-a1ef-ade237677df0">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="month" class="java.lang.String"/>      
        <parameter name="SOME_CHART_PARAM" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>

But got SAXParseException seems parameter not allowed inside subDataset.
 Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":parameter}'. One of '{"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":field, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":sortField, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":variable, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":filterExpression, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":group}' is expected.

Tried to add through JasperStudio but add parameter does not provide option to manually edit parameter name.


The parameter needs to be defined in the subdataset before the query string:
<subDataset name="chartDataset" uuid="f9034d6f-c83f-446d-a1ef-ade237677df0">
    <parameter name="SOME_CHART_PARAM" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="month" class="java.lang.String"/>      
</subDataset>

In Jaspersoft Studio you need to define the parameter in the Outline view under the subdataset/Paramters, select the parameter in the Outline view and set its name in the Properties view.

